# Ionic 4 PWA only app needs cordova-plugin-ionic-webview

Tags: angular, typescript, cordova-plugins, ionic4, progressive-web-apps

I need to convert Ionic 4 native mobile app to PWA only app. i.e. no native builds hereafter. I have followed [this doc](https://ionicframework.com/docs/publishing/progressive-web-app) and use Capacitor plugin for Network, camera and etc. My idea is to remove all the Cordova and Ionic native wrapper from the app.

My question here is Can I remove the `cordova-plugin-ionic-webview` and its native wrapper from the app?

**Note:** This PWA app works on a mobile device using its own hosting (`https`) service. i.e. no native build

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it can be removed. Since it's a Cordova plugin, it won't work on the web anyway.